# In Rust, is it possible to return a static function from a function?

Tags: rust, functional-programming

Suppose I have the following type in Rust:

```rust
type UnOp = fn(u64) -> u64;
```

That type allows me to create different unary operations:

```rust
const add1 : UnOp = |x| x + 1;
const mul2 : UnOp = |x| x * 2;
```

Now, suppose that I needed `add2`, `add3`, `add4` (...), for different numbers, in different places of my code. Writing all definitions would be cumbersome, so, instead, I write a generic `adder` function:

```rust
fn adder(add : u64) -> UnOp {
  |x| x + add
}
```

This would allow me to write `add(2)`, `add(3)`, etc., for any number:

```rust
// Prints 2 + 40
println!("result is: {}", adder(2)(40))
```

The problem is: `adder` is actually not valid Rust code, since `|x| ...` is a closure, not a static function. In order for `adder` to work as I want, I need to modify `UnOp` to be a closure instead:

```rust
type UnOp = Box<dyn Fn(u64) -> u64>;

fn adder(add : u64) -> UnOp {
  Box::new(move |x| x + add)
}
```

**The problem is: what if I know every usage of `adder(N)` is applied to a static value?**

In that case, creating dynamic closures would be wasteful, computation-wise. Not only that, `Box<dyn ...>` greatly complicates the code, and may even need lifetime annotations. My question is:

**Is it possible to create `adder`, without modifying the original definition of `UnOp`? That is, letting `UnOp` be a static function, NOT a closure?**

Logically, there is no reason it shouldn't be possible, as long as the arguments of `adder` are static, Rust should be able to just expand it at compile time, to generate each particular instance.

---

**Edit: additional details**

A great solution, proposed by @Netwave's answer, is to use Generic consts, which solves this problem for the specific example I gave. Sadly, it doesn't work in case `UnOp` is polymorphic, or if the constant argument is itself a function:

```
type UnOp<A> = fn(A) -> A;

pub fn adder<const ADD: u64>() -> UnOp<u64> {
  |x| ADD + x
}

pub fn apply<A, const op : UnOp<A>, const x : A>() -> A {
  return op(x);
}
```

This raises 2 errors:

```
- the type of const parameters must not depend on other generic parameters

- using function pointers as const generic parameters is forbidden
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [`const Generics`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html):

```rust
type UnOp = fn(u64) -> u64;


const fn adder<const ADD: u64>(x: u64) -> u64 {
    ADD + x
}

fn main() {
    let add_1: UnOp = adder::<1>;
    println!("{}", add_1(1));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b7f829c8a1a10a62be40eb4b577e08d3)

Comment: That is amazing, and is exactly what I was looking for. But I noticed it doesn't work if `UnOp` is polymorphic, or if the const argument is a function. I've edited the question to show an example where this solution doesn't work. I wonder if there is a way to circumvent this limitation? Regardless, your answer is spot-on, even though it doesn't cover my actual case.

Comment: @MaiaVictor I think you should have open a new related question and **not edited** the original one.

Comment: okay, I'll do so later. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create adder, without modifying the original definition of UnOp? That is, letting UnOp be a static function, NOT a closure?

Since you don't explain why I will ignore this requirement. As I think you limit you option for nothing.

You could prefer a clever use of generic and trait:

```rust
trait UnOp {
    fn call(&self, _: u64) -> u64;
}

impl<F> UnOp for F
where
    F: Fn(u64) -> u64,
{
    fn call(&self, x: u64) -> u64 {
        self(x)
    }
}

fn adder(add: u64) -> impl UnOp {
    move |x| x + add
}
```

Comment: I explain why. Aren't dynamic closures more expensive than static functions? Code-wise it is harder to maintain, too, due to the added bloat.

Comment: @MaiaVictor not really, a closure is just a function that can capture environment, you could do it by hand without problem it's would just be longer to write. Note that in my example, the closure is invisible to the user, you could return a `Fn(u64) -> u64` instead but them you expose the implementation of UnOp, your choice.

Comment: I need to think about it. My code did use closures, but that caused it to need a lifetime annotations, `Rc<dyn ...>`, I had to `.clone()` the closure in several places. [Here](https://github.com/Kindelia/LambdaVM-Rust/blob/master/src/parser.rs) is the actual code (the `Parser` type is the one in question). It was messy code-wise, and I thought it would be expensive, which is why I decided to rewrite `Parser` to use `fn() ...` instead of `Rc<dyn Fn() ...>`. Am I in the wrong track?

Comment: @MaiaVictor if you want a combinator parser you could take a look at nom, I myself coding one that I didn't release yet still working on it. `dyn Fn` is very different of `Fn`. My code example doesn't use dyn. Nom neither. all is generic.

Comment: I don't like `nom` though, so I'm making something that is more straightforward

Comment: Just a question, if `dyn Fn` is different from `Fn`, then why Rust forces you to write `dyn Fn` when you attempt to make an alias like `type UnOp = Fn(u64) -> u64`? It complains that `trait objects without an explicit dyn are deprecated`.